# GA/360: Account User Access Time via API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way via Google Analytics Management API (or other related API) to list when account users have last accessed Analytics? I've been poring through [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) but haven't found anything, though it's certainly possible I've missed it or perhaps there's another clever way to get the info.

I know this is possible to view in the 360 Organization settings, but it would be great if we could get user access time via API.

Use case is part of automating our Analytics permissions process and, for users who are not actually using Analytics, revoke access after a certain period of inactivity after a reminder email. We have a lot of Analytics users for multiple properties across multiple locations and are in need of a more automated permissions process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately this is not currently possible via the APIs**. You were right the Management API would be the place to look. However the only user information returned by the API are the user references to [profiles/views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileUserLinks/list), [properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/list), and [accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks#resource). For each of these, the only information returned about users is:

```
  "userRef": {
    "kind": "analytics#userRef",
    "id": string,
    "email": string
  },
```

That being said, I invite you to keep an eye on the Management API as it's being updated from time to time.

**If you want to raise a feature request**, [do it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187400&template=765802):

> This is the place to report bugs or feature requests with the Google
>   Analytics API. If that does not describe your use case, please review
>   the other resources available here:
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/help/